# Indexing on sampled Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've been puzzled again by pandas dataframe indexing under Python context . I tried to get the first element of a column, by calling `df[colname][0]`. However, it worked for a dataframe directly read from file but did not work for a sampled/sliced dataframe with reporting the error `KeyError 0'. May I ask what happened here? Any blogs/tutorials on this index problem? Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for accepting. If the answer was helpful, you can upvote them as well. Click on the little triangle above the answer score to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sampled DataFrame may or may not have the 0th element.

```
df
   Index                C1
0      1  [dinner, dinner]
1      2    [brunch, food]
2      3   [dinner, fancy]

df.sample(1)
   Index               C1
2      3  [dinner, fancy]
```

So, it makes sense that `df_sample[0]` may or may not work, since `df_sample[0]` looks for 0 in the index, rather than returning the first row. For the latter, use

`df_sample.iloc[0]`.

Comment: I see. This explanation did solve my confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to have a ][ in your code. That returns unexpected results sometimes because you wouldn't be working on the actual copy frame but on an internal copy. So use this instead

```
df.iloc[0, x] # if the column you need is the xth one, then it is x, you can know by calling df.columns and see which one it is if you have a small sample. 
df.loc[index, columnname] # this works the same way but instead of dealing with index numbers it uses their names
```

or you could do

temp = df.iloc[0]
temp['Column']